# Problems in the While Loop: Adding a thing to the list only once

Tags: vb.net, loops

I want to make restaurant bookings. As long as the guest is in the hotel, the guest should eat in the morning, at noon and in the evening. I have a `booking_of_restaurant` class for this. In the form in which the hotel reservation is made, the restaurant is then also booked for the period in question.
My code still books way too much – it would be enough to have one breakfast, one lunch and one dinner . I can't think of how to solve it.

Both start and end dates are given in text boxes with the time. The time is therefore not the default 12 A.M.

`Restaurant_reservations As New List(Of booking_of_restaurant)`

```
Private Sub Button_addGuest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_addGuest.Click
       

        Dim currentDate As Date = Start_date
        

        While currentDate < End_date
            If currentDate.Hour >= 7 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 11 Then
                Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
                                                                      booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.breakfast,
                                                                      characteristic))

            ElseIf currentDate.Hour > 11 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 14 Then
                Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
                                                                      booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.lunch,
                                                                      characteristic))
            ElseIf currentDate.Hour >= 18 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 22 Then
                Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
                                                                      booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.dinner,
                                                                      characteristic))
            End If
            currentDate = currentDate.AddHours(1)
        End While
 End Sub
```

I tried this, but the error is

> "booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals" is an enumeration type and cannot be used as an expression.

```
If Not Restaurant_reservations.Last().kind_of_meals = booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.breakfast Then
            End If
```

Comment: To me it seems that you don't need the entire while loop just the 3 `Restaurant_reservations.Add(...)` statements one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stepping in steps of 1 hour, so the loop is entering for instance the first block ten times (at 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, ...). So probably the easiest would be, stepping to the upper limit of the range, once a booking is made

```
Private Sub Button_addGuest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_addGuest.Click
  Dim currentDate As Date = Start_date
  Dim addHours as Integer = 1
  While currentDate < End_date
    If currentDate.Hour > 0 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 11 Then
      Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
        booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.breakfast,
        characteristic))
      addHours = 11 - currentDate.Hour

    ElseIf currentDate.Hour > 11 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 14 Then
      Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
        booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.lunch,
        characteristic))
      addHours = 14 - currentDate.Hour

    ElseIf currentDate.Hour >= 18 AndAlso currentDate.Hour < 22 Then
      Restaurant_reservations.Add(New booking_of_restaurant(currentDate,
        booking_of_restaurant.kind_of_meals.dinner,
        characteristic))
      addHours = 22 - currentDate.Hour

    End If

    currentDate = currentDate.AddHours(addHours)
  End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help.
To everyone who will read this in the future:
For this solution it is necessary that the operator reads like this: **>=**

Comment: @Daniel Well, that depends on what you want. If you use `>` you won't be able to book lunch for a customer at 11:00, but only starting with 12:00. If you use `>=` it will already be available at 11:00 ....